# Android App to automatically MOVE files from folders on one device to a folder on another device when connected to Wifi?

Tags: android, file-synchronization, google-apps, synchronization

I have one Android device (devA) I take with me and another Android device I always leave at home (devB).

Whenever I get home and devA connects to my Wifi, I need all files in specific folder(s) on devA to be automatically moved to a single folder on devB.

By "move" I mean that the individual files need to be automatically deleted on devA as soon as each have been successfully transferred to devB.

Note that the new files on the specific target folder in devB will eventually be removed once they have been moved there and will not be there forever.

What is the best App to do exactly this easily, directly, seamlessly, and automatically without me having to worry about it once it's all setup (set it and forget it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)** can do this (I'm using [its paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) for years). It lets you define "folder pairs" consisting of a local directory matched to a remote directory, and have them sync'd e.g. whenever a certain WiFi is available. *FolderSync* supports multiple protocols (like SFTP or WebDAV) and cloud services (like Dropbox, ownCloud/Nextcloud).

Of course that would mean that your "devB" is reachable by such means, so you'd need to run something like an [SSH Server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients#group_388) or [FTP-Server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_ftp) on it.

*FolderSync* lets you define the sync mode: bi-directional, uni-directional, and (with the latter) also whether to remove transferred files on the originating devices on success.

[image] [image]
<sup>*FolderSync* (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

There are also apps dedicated to [Peer2Peer sync](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync#group_1089), but not having used any of thos I've no idea if they'd fit your needs. *FolderSync* on "devA" with e.g. [SimpleSSHD](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.galexander.sshd/) on "devB" should however do the trick just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using "FolderSync" with "SSH/SFTP Server - Terminal" (both free apps on the Play store) and they were very easy to setup and worked like a charm.

Comment: Wonderful – thanks for the feedback, which will be really helpful for others in a similar situation. Enjoy! :) \o/